# Lose my global variables in javascript using Yii

Tags: javascript, yii, external

I am learning how to do server side scripting with the Yii framework. I am referencing a custom javascript file, however I am losing the global variable I created just for testing purposes saying x is not defined. When I tested it calling it directly through an HTML, I wasn't having this problem. Could someone please explain why I would lose the global variable using the Yii?

This is my testing code

```
var x = 4;

 window.onload= function test(){
     alert("This is the test function"); 
}
```

When I go to console after and type in x I get "variable is undefined". Curious as to why.

Answer (score 0):

this has nothing to do with Yii or MVC.

I think that is a matter of scopes which your variable is defined, check these links out:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

http://javascriptissexy.com/javascript-variable-scope-and-hoisting-explained/

however **without your full code** it's very hard to determine why that's undefined!